# Two scripts do the "same" thing but one works perfectly and the other doesnt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts that will do mostly the same thing, which is call a coroutine, and slowly regen stamina. Thing is in the second script, it instantly fills the stamina up to max, when the other increases it by 5 every second

This doesn't make any sense cause I basically copied the second script part from the first, and the first works perfectly. I have no idea why

https://pastebin.com/pE1vjisj

Has all my code, but the important stuff is this:

```
(Not working)
    void StopSprinting()
    {
        isSprinting = false;
        moveSpeed = 5;

        CallStam();
    }

    async void CallStam()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2500);

        player.SetStamBool();
    }
```

```
(Works perfectly)
    void Melee()
    {
        Vector2 attackDetectionPosition = attackDetection.position;
        Vector2 attackDirection = attackDetectionPosition + movementDirection;
 
        Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackDirection, attackRange, enemyLayers);

        foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
        {
            Debug.Log("We hit " + enemy.name);
        }
 
        if (player.CurrentStamina > 10)
        {
            player.CurrentStamina -= 10;
 
            //Deal Damage
 
            player.StamRegen = false;
            CallStam();
        }
        else if (player.CurrentStamina > 0)
        {
            //Deal half damage

            player.StamRegen = false;
            CallStam();
        }
    }

    async void CallStam()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2500);

        player.SetStamBool();
    }
```

```
    public void SetStamBool()
    {
        StamRegen = true;

        StartCoroutine(RegenerateStamina());
    }

    IEnumerator RegenerateStamina()
    {
        while (StamRegen == true && CurrentStamina < MaxStamina)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

            CurrentStamina += 5;
        }

        if (CurrentStamina > MaxStamina)
        {
            int subtractionAmount = CurrentStamina - MaxStamina;

            CurrentStamina -= subtractionAmount;
        }
    }
```

Sorry if I don't respond for a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: These are **not** doing the same! In the one hat is working you set

```
player.StamRegen = false;
```

in the other one you forgot that so it is possible that another routine is still running at the same time.

In general you could being end up with multiple parallel runnin routines!

---

Either way your mixing in of the async calls is not good! I would rather explicitly interrupt any running Coroutine and simply put the initial delay into the routine itself!

In the player have

```
// holds the currently running routine
private Coroutine _currentStaminaRegenaration;

public void RegenerateStamina(float initialDelay)
{
    // if there is already a routine running stop it
    if(_currentStaminaRegenaration != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(_currentStaminaRegenaration);
    }

    _currentStaminaRegenaration = StartCoroutine(RegenerateStaminaRoutine(initialDelay));
}

IEnumerator RegenerateStaminaRoutine(float initialDelay)
{
    // before starting the regeneration first run your initial delay
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(initialDelay);

    while (CurrentStamina < MaxStamina)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        CurrentStamina += 5;
    }

    // Instead of your complex check and subtraction simply use 
    CurrentStamina = Mathf.Min(CurrentStamina, MaxStamina);

    // never sure if this is needed but just in case reset
    _currentStaminaRegenaration = null;
}
```

and now everywhere instead of

```
player.StamRegen = false;
CallStam();
```

all you need to do is calling

```
player.RegenerateStamina(2.5f);
```

if the `2.5f` seconds is the same delay everywhere anyway you ca as well code it directly into the Coroutine itself then you don't even need to pass it in as parameter.

Comment: I have StamRegen = false`l in the Sprint function since I don't want them to regn stamina when they are sprinting

Comment: Sorry for second one, pressed enter on accident. Anyway, as for delay, I want it to wait 2.5 seconds, then every second increase Stamina by 5. I should probably set it to a if StamRegen = true call SetStamBool but yeah. I didn't know the Min fuction existed, so thank you for that. I will certainly try the null part, thanks!

Comment: You are a genius, it works finally. I spent all day and night trying to fix this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that the `StopSprinting` function is being called over and over again which makes `WaitForSeconds` redundant. You need to find a way to only trigger the coroutine function once, and here is my suggestion:

```
public void SetStamBool()
{
    if(!StamRegen){
        StamRegen = true;
        StartCoroutine(RegenerateStamina());
    }
}
```

Running should obviously set `StamRegen` to false for this logic to work.

On a side note, you should know that you can use a boolean on its own as a condition. So `StamRegen == true` is the very same as `StamRegen` on its own. Also, please keep the same casing convention for all your variables not to mix them with function names or classes, so `StamRegen` should be camelCase `stamRegen` to match the variable casing that you are following.

Comment: StamRegen is a public variable, as so I make my public have a capital at the beginning too, sorry. Thanks so much though I really appreciate it!

Comment: I see! If you are following such convention, then it is totally okay, I thought it was a typo or a segment from another code.